# How to change link colour with each session

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, session, cookies

Im trying to work out a way to change the hover link color for a site on each session.

Ive got some javascript that can change the hover color on each hover...

```
<script>
    var colors = Array("#A3F8EF", "#FF7275", "#CBB6E7", "#FF9D74", "#FDF874"),
        idx;
    $("div a").hover(function() {
        idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); // Pick random index
        $(this).css("background-color", colors[idx]);
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
    });
</script>
```

But im not sure how to only do this one each session? Thinking possibly using this javascript https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

with something like

```
 if($.cookie("visited")){ //hover color set } else { //set hover color
 }
```

but any other suggestions would be great

---MORE INFO---

just found this website that does pretty much what I want, but changes each day rather than on refresh. http://www.intworks.com/ Not quite sure how its been done though?

Comment: What do you mean by 'session'? JavaScript is client based, so has no connection to the server-side session, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When you store a session you do it by cookies. cookies can be reached and modified by both PHP and JS.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf The OPs mention of cookies was edited in, but it now makes it clearer what he means. Also, you should note that Session data is not always stored in cookies. It can also be kept on the server side in memory or in a data store.

Comment: What is expected result if user clears cookies , Storage each time browser closes ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
    //enter your code here to work on the initial session
        localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
    });
}
```

Have you had a look into HTML5 local storage? I found it quite useful and looks as though it could apply here. Just something to consider. (Above snippet I used in jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

One solution Is to make 2 more cookie `whatsession` and `color` and store the current session in `whatsession`.
in your JS code just check if the current session is equal to the cookie `whatsession`.
If both were equal then just use the color in `color` cookie.
If not, change the color cookie and update `whatsession` cookie to the new session.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been experimenting with the answer from Matt, and think Ive foiund a working solution as follows:

```
<script>
    if (localStorage.getItem("visited") != "true") {
        var colors = Array("#A3F8EF", "#FF7275", "#CBB6E7", "#FF9D74", "#FDF874"),
            idx;
        idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); // Pick random index
        sessionStorage.setItem("colour", colors[idx]);
        newColour = sessionStorage.getItem("colour");
    }
    document.getElementById("creditsTitle").style.color = newColour;
    $("div a").hover(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", newColour);
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
    });
    sessionStorage.setItem("visited", "true");
</script>
```

This seems to be working ok but Im sure could be improved further.